# Using in-built methods of django query

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-models, query-optimization

I have a method which computes the following. Can we use select_related or any optimisation here as well?

```
obj = []
for game in Games.objects.filter(query__health=health,created_at__gte=start_date.replace(month=month_to_consider,year=year_to_consider)).distinct().order_by('-created_at'):
 data={}
 data["problem"] = game.issue.issue if game.issue else ""
 data["game_name"]=game.name
 obj.append(data)
```

return obj

Comment: Can you post code for `get_cities` method?

Comment: @ohduran, any suggests for the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information that you have been providing, there is an issue with the number of times you hit your database, which gives you room for improvement.

For instance, when you do `PlCityAssociate.objects.filter(play__states__city=city...`, you're making a call to states, then cities, that match your criteria. That's 3 calls to DB, each time you go over it within the `for` loop.

The create method is not creating anything, which seems weird, but I'll follow along. What you may be trying to show is the list of cities that belong to the user, with status equals to A, B, or C, and with client.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = City.objects.select_related('citystatus').filter(owner=request.user, citystatus__status__in=["A", "B", "C"], client_id__isnull=False)
    res = []
    for r in queryset:
        res.append(self.get_cities(r))
    return Response(res)
```

Django allows you to do joins on the fly using `select_related()`, which you can find more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/).

The second part, the `get_cities()` method, that I would include it within the City model, so that you can call it for each instance instead of running a loop through all the PlCityAssociate queryset each time.

So the new `get_cities()` method **inside the City model** would look like this:

```
def get_cities(self ,city):
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    pls = self.state_set.all().play_set.all().plcityassociate_set.filter(update_at__gte=start_date)
```

Do let me know whether that's enough improvement. Also, make sure you test the number of times you hit the database, there are several ways to do that, but my preferred one is [`django_assert_num_queries`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#django_assert_num_queries), which is part of [`pytest-django`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: @timshrok could you please update your question with a brief schema of how your models are related to? I understand that City points to User via the owners field, but everything else is flurry.

Comment: What about PlCity? Can you expand on its model relationship with the others?

Comment: @timshrok have a look at my updated answer and do let me know whether it works.

Comment: it works now. But, can we optimise the City.objects.filter() in create method? Like I am thinking to have the fields required in get_cities() method here itself by using values() method.

Comment: The moment you do `for r in queryset:`, the database is hit. So it's best if you filter as much as you can before that for loop, instead of pushing all the filtering logic at the end. Most of the improvement in performance will come from doing just that.

Please if you find that the answer was what you were looking for, please accept it, it would mean the world to me.

Comment: hi @timshrok I'm afraid that's all you can get as far as I'm concerned with regards to the queryset.

Comment: ohhkay @ohduran, just one last thing... any improvements related to Update 4?